# Different sizes in JavaFX on different screens

Tags: java, javafx, size, resolution, borderpane

I've been struggling to make my JavaFX application size properly on different devices. I think it happens because of different resolutions on the screens. I'm doing all the development on my Macbook Pro Retina 13, which has a resolution of `2560x1600`, while the window looks different on my Windows desktop which runs `1920x1080`. I'll illustrate with two pictures.

### 2560x1600

[image: 2560x1600]

### 1920x1080

[image: 1920x1080]

My first guess was that it was because the BorderPane would increase in size on 1920x1080. So I tried to fix the size with the following code.

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="304.0" maxWidth="414.0" minHeight="304.0" 
minWidth="414.0" prefHeight="304.0" prefWidth="414.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.GUIController">
```

This didn't change anything, though. Any ideas how to address this problem?

**EDIT:** I want it to look like on `2560x1600` basically.

**EDIT:** The FXML file looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.GUIController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane>
         <center>
            <ScrollPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane>
                     <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="itemList" prefHeight="214.0" prefWidth="412.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" editable="false" resizable="false" text="Name" />
                            <TableColumn fx:id="powerColumn" editable="false" resizable="false" text="Power" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="typeColumn" editable="false" resizable="false" text="Type" />
                          </columns>
                           <columnResizePolicy>
                              <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                           </columnResizePolicy>
                        </TableView>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </center>
         <bottom>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <HBox prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="6.0" />
                  <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="37.0" text="Item: ">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Regular" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="newCBox" onAction="#addItemClicked" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="112.0" promptText="New" />
                  <HBox prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#importClicked" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="64.0" text="Import" />
                  <HBox prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="5.0" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#removeClicked" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="Remove" />
                  <HBox prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="5.0" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#upgradeClicked" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="72.0" text="Upgrade" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </bottom>
         <top>
            <VBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="414.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <MenuBar>
                    <menus>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem fx:id="savedMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveClicked" text="Save" />
                              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                              <MenuItem fx:id="openMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openClicked" text="Open" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Item">
                          <items>
                              <MenuItem fx:id="editItemMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#editItemClicked" text="Edit" />
                              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                            <MenuItem fx:id="importMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#importClicked" text="Import" />
                              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                              <MenuItem fx:id="removeMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#removeClicked" text="Remove" />
                              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                              <MenuItem fx:id="upgradeMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#upgradeClicked" text="Upgrade" />
                          </items>
                        </Menu>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Profile">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem id="editValues" fx:id="editValues" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#editValuesClicked" text="Edit &amp; New" />
                              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#shareProfileClicked" text="Share Profile" />
                              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadProfileClicked" text="Load Profile" />
                              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#removeProfileClicked" text="Remove" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#aboutClicked" text="About" />
                              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#newsClicked" text="News" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                    </menus>
                  </MenuBar>
                  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                     <children>
                        <HBox prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="5.0" />
                        <Label text="Display: " />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="displayCBox" onAction="#displayChanged" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="149.0" promptText="Display type" />
                        <HBox prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="59.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="profileCBox" onAction="#profileChanged" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="143.0" promptText="Choose Profile" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </top>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you say explicitly what the issue is? Is it the space on the right between the "Choose Profile" combo and the edge of the window (and similarly the "Upgrade" button)? Can you post the FXML for the layout?

Comment: The problem is the space right of the TableView. I want it to reach the right edge like it does on the higher resolution screen. I added  the fxml file too.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of redundant nodes in that layout. E.g. there is an anchor pane containing only the border pane; why not just make the border pane the root element? Similarly, the table is the only child of an anchor pane; again, you can remove the anchor pane entirely. I'm not sure why there is a scroll pane; tables manage their own scrolling. Using `padding` and `spacing` on the `HBox` instead of empty panes. I would start by simplifying the layout, and probably removing the explicit sizing (`prefWidth` and `prefHeight` on the table, for example).

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I used Scene Builder and they added those anchors panes, so I assumed it was the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like James_D pointed out in comment, there was redudant nodes in my code. I had used Scene Builder and they added unneeded anchors panes by default, so I made the assumption that it was accurate. However, it's not.